# display only surname using graph api. is it possible?

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i have results returned from a friends list, however i would prefer there to only be the forename to be returned rather than the full name.

is this possible.

also, how could i make the profile image bigger when displayed?

i have tried to use "first_name" but comes back as an Undifined Index.

here is the code i have:

```
if ($user) {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

echo '<table>';
foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="pic">';
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<font color="white">','<div class="picName">'.$value["first_name"].'</div>','</font>';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: perhaps you have to parse for the first name as the api only returns the full name. it probably isn't too hard to parse especially if you use regex.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the first name with this call:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=first_name');
```

Also, what do you mean by making the profile image bigger? Do you need something like this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#sizes

Answer (score 1):

I added this answer to one of your other questions, but it applies here as well:

You can use FQL to make an SQL-like query that can limit and randomize the records returned. You can get any public field of the friends this way.
Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT uid, first_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12;
```

To use FQL with the PHP SDK, use this format:

```
$facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql
));
```

, `$fql` being the query.

Check out the [Technical Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) and the [Table Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) of FQL.

**EDIT:** To get a larger picture, add ?width=x&height=y to the end of the source URL.
It won't necessarily be the exact size you request, but Facebook will return its closest match. So the URL would look like this for a 220×220 px image:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/picture?width=220&height=220
```

I got a 320×320px large image this way, but you can always resize it with the `<img>` tag's `width` and `height` attributes.